# "launchctl start error: Bad file descriptor" when trying to start Neo4j server

Tags: macos, neo4j

After trying to start the server, I get the error "launchctl start error: Bad file descriptor".

I've tried to restart the computer and reinstalled Neo4j too.

I'm running the M03 version of 2.0 on my mac, with latest updates.

Comment: Can you post the exact error? Is this only with M03?

Comment: Are you trying to start the server as a service? Just did it locally on my mac, all good.

Answer (score 2):

I had to remove it from launchd and then it would work, like this:

```
balinjdl-mac:local balinjdl$ neo4j start
WARNING! You are using an unsupported version of the Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Dneo4j.ext.udc.source=homebrew
Detected installation in launchd, starting it...
launchctl start error: Bad file descriptor

balinjdl-mac:local balinjdl$ neo4j remove

balinjdl-mac:local balinjdl$ neo4j start
WARNING! You are using an unsupported version of the Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Dneo4j.ext.udc.source=homebrew
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [36824]... waiting for server to be ready......... OK.
Go to http://localhost:7474/webadmin/ for administration interface.
balinjdl-mac:local balinjdl$
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I had a slightly different approach than @balinjdl (his seems smoother, but in case it doesn't work for someone), I removed it from launchctl directly.

First find the entry in launchctl:

```
$ launchctl list | grep neo
-       2   org.neo4j.server.7474
```

Next remove it:

```
$ launchctl remove org.neo4j.server.7474
```

Now you can install it again, which will also start it, with:

```
$ neo4j install
```

I'm had to do this going from M03 to M05 using homebrew. Seeing as it was an issue for you with previous versions, I imagine this will probably be something you need to do whenever you upgrade neo4j.

Good luck!