# launchctl start error: Bad file descriptor when trying to start NEO4J server

Tags: neo4j

Yesterday neo4j was working as expected, and today it isn't. I'm getting the following error:

```
unknownc8e0eb17b72f% ./bin/neo4j status
Neo4j Server is not running
unknownc8e0eb17b72f% ./bin/neo4j start 
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC   
Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties - 
Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -
Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -
XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
Detected installation in launchd, starting it...
launchctl start error: Bad file descriptor
```

Running ./bin/neo4j console does not cause problems and I can see my graphs using the web tool on my localhost.

Perhaps related, I'm using jexp's batch-import tool to import my data and the labels aren't coming through.

I've tried restarting, deleting and redownloading, etc. I'm using the 2.0 RCI version of neo4j.

I saw the related questions from ~6 months ago but with the new 2.0 build and the fact that following the advice on that thread didn't work for me made me want to open a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it installed as a service. See this answer for how to uninstall:

["launchctl start error: Bad file descriptor" when trying to start Neo4j server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013863/launchctl-start-error-bad-file-descriptor-when-trying-to-start-neo4j-server)

Comment: I tried that, now both neo4j start and neo4j console are failing. I'm a big confused as to why neo4j was working yesterday and is not working today.

Comment: Alright, did the steps again and it works now. This is the second time that this has happened - it seems like neo4j magically stops working, I flail around for a bit, then it magically starts working.